# are SIP IP addresses static for IBM Voice Agent?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-voice-gateway

IBM Voice Agent provides SIP domain names to configure Twilio etc.

- sip:us-south.voiceagent.cloud.ibm.com (169.61.56.226)
- sip:us-east.voiceagent.cloud.ibm.com (169.62.26.42)

Are these current IP addresses static?

Answer (score 1):

The IPs are static but SIP trunks should be configured using the domain names. The IPs that the domains resolve to may change due to infrastructure changes or updates but the domains will always be consistent.